# Adding file within function without having to call file. php

Tags: php, function

i have stumbled across an issue and really need some help

i have got a function below which i am using in a wordpress plugin.

here is the code.

```
 // Base function
function isd_s3player() {
// Plugin Url
$s3url = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
echo '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'.$s3url.'dewplayer-playlist.swf" width="235" height="200" id="dewplayer" name="dewplayer">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="movie" value="'.$s3url.'dewplayer-playlist.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="showtime=true&autoreplay=true&xml='.$s3url.'playlist.php&autostart=1" />
</object>';
}
```

ok the problem i am having is i cant passed the database variable to the playlist.php which the dewplayer needs to call within the function.

is their a way to somehow use or set the playlist.php in this function without having to call it seperatly???

Here is my playlist.php

```
<?php

$bucket = get_option("isd-bucket");
$folder = get_option("isd-folder");
//include the S3 class
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('s3/S3.php');

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'amazon key');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'amazon secret key');

//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

// Get the contents of our bucket
$bucket_contents = $s3->getBucket($bucket,$folder);

header("Content-type: text/xml");
$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n";
$xml_output .= '<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">\n';
$xml_output .= "<trackList>\n";
foreach ($bucket_contents as $file){



$fname = $file['name'];
$furl = "http://$amazon_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($fname);



if(preg_match("/\.mp3$/i", $furl))
{ 



 if (isset($outputted[$furl])) {
        continue;
    }

    $xml_output .= "\t<track>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<location>" . $furl . "</location>\n"; 

    $xml_output .= "\t\t<creator>" . $fname . "</creator>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<album>" . $fname . "</album>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<title>" .  basename($fname) . "</title>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<annotation>I love this song</annotation>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<duration>32000</duration>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<image>covers/smetana.jpg</image>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<info></info>\n";

$xml_output .= "\t\t<link>" . $furl . "</link>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t</track>\n";

$outputted[$furl] = true;
}
}
$xml_output .= "</trackList>";
echo $xml_output;
?>
```

ok so as you can see right at the top i am trying to grab two option from the database but it doesnt allow you to do it this way within wordpress.

So i guess what i am asking is their a way to completely skip the playlist.php file and do everything within the function???

Any help??

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Deal with what?

Comment: better or worse pekka???

Comment: You mean, you want to feed the XML data directly to the `object` tag? I don't know whether that is possible, I guess that will depend on the player you are using. But  why do this in the first place?

Comment: Hi yes thats right i know i really dont want to do this, but the way the plugin works is i need it to call two values from within the playlist.php. i have tried passing the both through via the url like this playlist.php?name='.$bucket.'&s3folder='.$folder.'&autostart=1" /> and have tried calling them via the playlist php file as you can see above.

Comment: But why can't you pass the variables? What doesn't work? It should be a simple matter of adding the variables like you show, and fetching them using `$_GET["folder"]` etc.

Comment: i know thats what i thought it grabs the name fine but not the s3folder is their an error in this code that i am missing ? <param name="flashvars" value="showtime=true&autoreplay=true&xml='.$s3url.'playlist.php?name='.$bucket.'&s3folder='.$folder.'&autostart=1" />   $bucket = $_GET["name"];
$folder = $_GET["s3folder"];

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working dont no why i have to do it the way but here it is.

function

$bucket = get_option("isd-bucket"); 
$folder = get_option("isd-folder");

$test = $bucket." ".$folder;

and in playlist

$bucket = $_GET["name"];

$pieces = explode(" ", $bucket);

$bucket_contents = $s3->getBucket($pieces[0],$pieces[1]);

if anyone nows why it wont work the other way please let me know